# How to tell when a key is pressed in Windows Mobile 6.5 (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, mobile, keypress

I am writing a windows mobile application and would like to be able to respond to key presses from the user. There are points in the app where I would like to wait for a keypress to continue. ex.

"Press any key to continue..."

How could I achieve that in c++? I was thinking something like:

```
MessageBox("Press any key to continue...");

while(isntPressed){
    if(a key is pressed){
        isntPressed=false;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.80).aspx

You can use the `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` events.